# Nameerror in flask db migrate - Table not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have run flask db upgrade for creating Todos table. Now I added a new table and established a relationship with the existing table and also added a new field in the existing table.

I would expect flask db migrate to record the differences (adding new table Todoslist and adding a new field in Todo) however it says name error - table not defined.

```
class TodoList(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'todolists'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
  todos.db.relationship('Todo', backref='list', lazy = True)


class Todo(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'todos'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
   completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
   list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(todolists.id), nullable=True)
```

**- Error details:**

```
File "C:\Users\rg\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\rg\class_demos\Todoapp\app.py", line 26, in <module>
    class Todo(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\rg\class_demos\Todoapp\app.py", line 32, in Todo
    list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(todolists.id), nullable=True)
NameError: name 'todolists' is not defined
```

**Solutions tried**

1. Flask app is set to the current python module
2. Tried swapping the create table (one before the other)
3. Searched extensively and this error seems to be common but not able to find a matching case like the one mentioned above.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from how you are creating a relationship between `Todo` and `TodoList` models.

`list_id` needs to be properly initialized as a foreign key to `TodoList.id`, which means that it references an `id` value from the `TodoList` table. You have incorrectly used `todolists.id`, which is a table that does not exist. Rather, you should define the `list_id` as:

```py
list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("todoList.id"))
```

To create the relationship in `TodoList` table, you will need to initialize the field `todos` with `db.relationship`. This is not an actual database field, but a high-level view of the relationship between `TodoList` and `Todo`, and for that reason it isn't in the database diagram. So, you can properly create the field as:

```py
todos = db.relationship('Todo', backref='list', lazy='True')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But Flask db migrate wont require the field to be declared as it will create those in the migration scripts.. I just found the blunder I did after spanning through for more than 24 hours..

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Missed the quotes for `todolists.id`

```py
list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("todolists.id"), nullable=True)
```

This fixed the issue :)